# Is there a graph algorithm to find shortest path between nodes, incorporating nodes to avoid?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

Let's say I have a graph with nodes that represent locations. Starting at some node N, I want to reach another node M via the shortest path possible. The catch is that there some nodes I want to *avoid*, staying some distance from them (say at least D nodes away).

Is there a graph algorithm that can solve the shortest path problem *with* the node avoidance requirement? Would a weighted graph (with infinite length edges emanating from the to-be-avoided nodes) be a solution here?

Comment: Couldn't you just temporarily remove the nodes you don't want to use?

Comment: That alone may not be sufficient since I want to have some buffer distance from those nodes as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temporarily eliminate the nodes you must avoid and those near them or change the weights of the appropriate edges to infinity. Then use any standard path-finding algorithm.